# Would like to resolve the error message in mac terminal everytime I open it. It runs for almost a minute everytime terminal is opened

Tags: unix, bash, macos, command-line, terminal

Mac terminal displays the following message every time I open. It runs for a minutes and more than 1000 lines long. What is the problem and how to resolve it? At the end of the message, the XQuartz terminates and dialogue appears. The output is the following followed by the relevant image. [XQuartz problem report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87mFE.png)

```
Last login: Fri Aug 27 11:14:59 on ttys000
-bash: ===============================================================: command not found
-bash: ===============================================================: command not found
-bash: jp2a-invert/Users/username/Desktop/1.jpg: No such file or directory
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 4: ===============================================================: command not found
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 15: ===============================================================: command not found
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 36: jp2a-invert/Users/username/Desktop/1.jpg: No such file or directory
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 4: ===============================================================: command not found
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 15: ===============================================================: command not found
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 36: jp2a-invert/Users/username/Desktop/1.jpg: No such [enter image description here][1]file or directory
/Users/atlantis/.bash_profile: line 4: ===============================================================: command not found
```

When I ran the command 'cat.bash_profile' the outout is the following

```
# added by Anaconda2 5.1.0 installer
export PATH="/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
===============================================================
#-------------------- New command --------------------#
LOCAL_SRC=${HOME}/src # Location to store source codes locally. Change if necessary.
LOCAL_PREFIX=${HOME} # Location to install libraries locally. Change if necessary.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LOCAL_PREFIX}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="${LOCAL_PREFIX}/include:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="${LOCAL_PREFIX}/include:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}"
export LIBRARY_PATH="${LOCAL_PREFIX}/lib:${LIBRARY_PATH}"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${LOCAL_PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
export PATH="${LOCAL_PREFIX}/bin:${PATH}"
===============================================================


##
# Your previous /Users/atlantis/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/atlantis/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2019-05-11_at_01:55:27
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2019-05-11_at_01:55:27: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
jp2a-invert/Users/username/Desktop/1.jpg


X
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the results of the terminal command : `cat .bash_profile`

Comment: This is coming from one of the shell login files. Apart from `.bash_profile`, also check the files `.profile` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: @DarkDust How do I do that? Would you kindly tell me?

Comment: By using a shell editor like `vi` or nano, or simply dump its content using `cat`. Like `cat .bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines with `=====` shouldn't be there, neither should the `jp2a-invert/Users/username/Desktop/1.jpg` line.

Open `.bash_profile` with the **text** editor of your choice (e.g. `nano .bash_profile`) and remove them.

Comment: You also only want one of the sets of the python setup lines eother 3.8 or 3.9 not both - although as you have macports I would remove both and install python from macports - there would be less things in the path and less installed

Comment: "You also only want one of the sets of the python setup lines either 3.8 or 3.9 not both"- do you mean, I should remove both python packages and reinstall via macports? @mmmmmm

Comment: No - this is just about editing ~/.bash_profile